# How to label all group records separately?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, shift

So I have records of each person spotted times in each store from this I want to label the groups differently based on time lag is 5 minutes or a new store id .The data is like below :

```
  DT1<-data.table(
  id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
  in_time=c("2017-11-01 08:37:35","2017-11-01 08:38:42","2017-11-01 08:39:45","2017-11-01 08:50:35","2017-11-01 08:51:35","2017-11-01 08:52:44","2017-11-01 08:53:16","2017-11-01 08:59:29"),
  store_id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)

  )
  DT1[,in_time:=ymd_hms(in_time)]
```

Then I use the below code to separate each groups.

```
DT1[,group:= cumsum(difftime(in_time, shift(in_time, fill=-Inf), units="mins") > 5), by=list(id,store_id)]
```

But then I get the same group again for same id. Is there any way to get different group ids for different groups (you can see group 1 repeating again at 2017-11-01 08:52:44).
Also, I have more than one id so that's why I group by id and store id.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) `DT1` is not accurately generated. `in_time` and `store_id` are shorter than `id`. 2) Can you show your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah sorry updated the data table .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `rleid` to get a unique index and include `store_id` in it.

```
library(data.table)
DT1[, group := rleid(store_id, cumsum(difftime(in_time, 
                shift(in_time, fill = first(in_time)), units = "mins") > 5)), id]

DT1

#   id             in_time store_id group
#1:  1 2017-11-01 08:37:35        1     1
#2:  1 2017-11-01 08:38:42        1     1
#3:  1 2017-11-01 08:39:45        1     1
#4:  1 2017-11-01 08:50:35        1     2
#5:  1 2017-11-01 08:51:35        1     2
#6:  1 2017-11-01 08:52:44        2     3
#7:  1 2017-11-01 08:53:16        2     3
#8:  1 2017-11-01 08:59:29        2     4
```